# Convert X,Y,Z Values to Matrixplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following lists:

```
x_list = [7,10,3,9,9]
y_list = [2,5,1,3,2]

z_list = [4,1,5,2,3]
```

For each `x` value and `y` value there is a `z`value. For example: `x=7`and `y=2`have the `z`value of `4`.

I would like to convert this into a matrix such as:

[image]

… to be able to create a matrix-plot with the correct x- and y- axis and a colorbar (colorbar is missing here, and it would be nice to have the zero values as black color):

[image]

It is rather straightforward to do in Excel, but I am having difficulties doing it in python, since I am quite new to matplotlib.

### Edit

I might use plt.imshow() to make the plot

Answer (score 1):

NumPy's [`unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) functions are your friends here to set up the proper grid from your coordinates. Then, you just need to find the proper indices in the resulting `X` and `Y`, that correspond to your coordinates. Finally, in some all-zero `Z` matrix with the same dimensions as `X` and `Y`, you can set the elements at the just found indices to your original `z` data.

Here's some code:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([7, 10, 3, 9, 9])
y = np.array([2,  5, 1, 3, 2])
z = np.array([4,  1, 5, 2, 3])

# Calculate X, Y grid from x and y, initialize Z data with zero
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.unique(x), np.unique(y))
Z = np.zeros(X.shape)

# Find proper indices in grid, and set Z values accordingly
idx = np.squeeze([np.argwhere(np.logical_and(X == x[idx], Y == y[idx])) for idx in np.int32(np.arange(x.size))])
Z[idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]] = z
print(Z)
```

And, the output is:

```
[[5. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 4. 3. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Regarding the plotting: I can't think of a Matplotlib function to create a plot similar to the shown. So, maybe give an additional hint, which function you have in mind.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer ! Maybe plt.imshow(Z), but I would not know how to set the colors and the color bar correctly